# Дискорд Бот повторяет свои сообщения

Tags: python, discord.py

Создаю Дискорд бота, и иногда появляется ошибка/баг: Бот повторяет свои сообщения, причём, появляется эта ошибка спонтанно и иногда она выдаёт подобное:

[image]

Здесь видно, что я применил команду .translate к сообщению, выполнилась она нормально, но здесь мы видим два вида сообщения, а всё потому что я изменил код и добавил знаки для отображения сообщения, потому они отличаются. То есть дело не в коде, а скорее в кэше или в чём-то другом, из-за чего бот дублируется, при этом, действует он по разным версиям кода. Почему так? Бывало, что я авторизовал бота заново, и это помогло, но иногда и нет. Помогите

Я не думаю, что ошибка в коде, поэтому не буду его прикреплять. Заранее спасибо

***Прошу прощения, данный пример плохо показывает суть, так как я нашёл решение данной проблемы  В КОДЕ, но сама суть остаётся, бот правда иногда дублирует сообщения без повода***

Вот здесь никаких проблем в коде нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Ошибка в коде может заключаться лишь в том случае, если присутствует дублирование кода, что в принципе маловероятно.
Вероятнее всего, у Вас запускается два экземпляра бота одновременно.

Если Вы запускаете код посредством IDE, проверьте конфигурацию запуска.
Также, возможно, что бот параллельно находится на хостинге. (если доступа к хостингу нет, попробуйте заново сгенерировать токен бота [в настройках приложений](https://discord.com/developers/applications))

API дискорда, как и большинство других, работает на обыкновенных REST API запросах. Кэшироваться сообщения просто никак не могут.
В крайнем случае, попробуйте обновить discord.py до последней версии.

*К сожалению, без подробной информации более исчерпывающего ответа дать нельзя.*

Comment: Спасибо! Я запускаю код через Pycharm, и перед тем как его снова запустить, я его останавливаю. Поэтому, очень странно, что такое вообще происходит.

Answer (score 1):

я тоже недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой. И, действительно, у меня остался один работающий экземпляр бота, я просто отключил его и все заработало как надо! :)